# PHP Return ID[uniqueidentifier] after sql INSERT

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

Like the title says, I want the id of a row to be returned after INSERT to the database.

I've got 2 functions, one to make a connection to the database:

```
function db_connect() {
    $host = "host";
    $user = "user";
    $pwd = "pwd";
    $database = "db";
    $con;
    try{
        $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server= ".$host." ; Database = ".$database." ", $user, $pwd);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        die(print_r($e));
    }
    return $conn;
}
```

And one to insert a new record:

```
function setTiptile($name,$cols,$rows) {
    $connect = db_connect();
    $query = "INSERT INTO data(ID, name, cols, rows) VALUES(NEWID(),?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $cols);
    $stmt->bindValue(3, $rows);
    $stmt->execute();


    return $connect->lastInsertId('ID'); // This should work, but doesn't, why?

}
```

I need the last function to return the ID of the inserted row, how should I do this?

**EDIT:**
Like the title says, the ID is an uniqueidentifier, no idea if that changes things.

**EDIT:** Ok, apparently I've got to use:`$connect->lastInsertId('ID');`, but this isn't returning anything at all. What can be the cause of that? The new row ís created in the database.

Comment: They're not using MySQL

Comment: I would like to point out that @JohnConde's comment is inaccurate - this works with SQL Server but only if the column has an identity insert - since uniqueidentifier doesn't have this option, this method won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(My) solution:**

The **parameter** of lastInsertId() has to be the **table name instead of the row name**. Besides that, the table must have a row with the parameter **IDENTITY checked**, this is the row which is returned.

That brings to the conclusion that it's **impossible to return a uniqueidentifier with lastInsertId**() since this cannot have the parameter IDENTITY checked.

Comment: Something else that will work is `INSERT INTO <table> [(column1, column2, ... ,columnN)] OUTPUT inserted.id_column VALUES('value1', 'value2', ..., 'valueN')`

Answer (score 1):

From the [Manual](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php):

> Returns the ID of the last inserted row, or the last value from a
>   sequence object, depending on the underlying driver. For example,
>   PDO_PGSQL() requires you to specify the name of a sequence object for
>   the name parameter.

It should be something like:

```
return $connect->lastInsertId('yourIdColumn');
```

Comment: tried this, isn't working! In my case it should be; return $connect->lastInsertId('ID'); right?

Comment: Yes Corrected my answer @Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Use [`lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

```
$conn->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 0):

why not first do a select newid()
and then use that id in the insert

Comment: Can you try to phrase this more as an answer than a question?

Comment: Welcome, and thank you @rolf oosting, what you wrote is more likely comment but not answer so rephrasing it in a more structured answer would be more organized.